# Interpreting results from a Poisson and Quasipoisson model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, overdispersion

I used Poisson regression model to model how count of user actions on a website (dependent variable) are explained by website content (independent variables). The dependent variable distribution is shown in this plot.

[image]

As you can see, the distribution is positively skewed and has a long tail. The results of the Poisson regression model from `glm` in R are shown here:

[image]

As you can see, residual deviance is much greater than the degrees of freedom, so there is overdispersion. Next, I tried Quasipoissson model that gave these results:

[image]

I see that the Quasipoisson model shows that none of the independent variables are significant. I am a little unsure how to interpret these results. Am I handling the overdispersion incorrectly, or am I using independent variables that just do not explain the variation in my dependent variable?

Comment: Welcome. It could be a convergence issue. But first, I wonder if there is a lot of zeros for subgroups of your covariates. Check the variation in your response for particular covariates such as `Active_Floorplans`. Try that and see if it fixes the problem. Please follow-up if this doesn’t address your concern.

Comment: @ThomasBilach After closer inspection of the independent variables, I am noticing both a lot of zeros and some rather large outliers. For example, `Active_Floorplans` has ~9% zeros and `Low_Price` has about 4% zeros. This is quite surprising to me due to the nature of this content. However, `Active_Photos` has about 1% zeros. When I use `LPP ~ Active_Photos` as the formula in the Poissson and Quasipoisson model, both do show significance for this variable. I would love to understand this at a deeper level if you can explain or point me to some appropriate reading material.

Comment: @ThomasBilach Actually, upon closer inspection it appears that `Low_Price` was the real problem. The Poisson and Quasipoisson models show significance for all variables as long as I drop `Low_Price` from the model. This variable is discrete/count variable with 4% zeros and a lot of subgroups. Here is a description of that distribution: range = 0-10000, Q1 = 750, Median = 975, Q3 = 1055.

Comment: So for certain combinations of covariates, it appears there isn’t enough variation in your response. You might wish to enter a factorized version of a regressor on the right-hand side that has multiple subgroups, only to learn that there is a predominance of zeros within that subgroup. This is the likely diagnosis. After dropping some of the variables, can you estimate both models?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Yes, I believe you have solved my problem, and I believe I follow your suggestions about regressor factorization. If you want to write your above comments as an answer, I will mark it as solved. I really appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues are likely at play here. One is a convergence failure. The other is adjusting for a covariate(s) with low-cardinality. The likely diagnosis is the latter.

For instance, `Low_Price` and `Numeric_Rank` have small estimates of uncertainty and consequently large z-values. This should make you suspicious of your model inputs (covariates). For certain combinations of covariates, there appears to be little to no variation in your response variable. I would assess summaries of `LPP` by covariate. You might observe a lot of 0's for one particular input. To get around this, you might have to consider dropping a particular covariate or aggregating your data to obtain cleaner estimates.

In the comments, I noted that this often occurs when you blindly throw predictors on the right-hand side of your equation. By "factorized" version of a variable, I meant a variable with many categories (levels). See the basic specification below:

```
poisson <- glm(LPP ~ as.factor(Floor_Plan) + ..., family = "poisson", data = ...)
```

where `Floor_Plan` might be a multivalued factor variable with many levels. R will attempt estimation of all levels of this variable. For any particular subgroup, there might be predominance of 0 counts. This is just something to consider as you make your model more complex. I hope this helps with your intuition.

As a final thought, there are other ways to estimate overdispersion. In the AER package you will find the function `dispersiontest`, which implements a test for [overdispersion](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030440769090014K) by Cameron & Trivedi (1990). Here is the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-9/topics/dispersiontest).